# ¿Cómo compilar y ejecutar varios .java en Linux?

Tags: java, java-8, javac

Tengo tres archivos `.java` y para compilar en el terminal hago lo siguiente:

```
javac nombredelarchivo1.java nombredelarchivo2.java nombredelarchivo3.java
```

Hasta ahí bien, pero para ejecutar, utilizo:

```
java nombredelarchivo1 nombredelarchivo2 nombredelarchivo3
```

Pero si lo hago de esta manera arroja el siguiente error:

> "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal
>   nombredelarchivo".

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede pasar? 
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java tienes?

Comment: Estoy en una máquina virtual y me sale que tengo la versión 1.8.0_131

Comment: Solo debes ejecutar la clase que contiene el main, no las 3

Comment: Ejecuté solo la clase que contenía el main y aún así, me salía "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal nombredelarchivo".

Comment: en `nombredelarchivo1.java` tienes `public class nombredelarchivo{`?

Answer (score 1):

cuando te dice que no se encuentra "nombreDelArchivo" lo que esta es diciendo que hay una diferencia entre el nombre de la clase la cual parece ser "nombreDelArchivo" y el nombre del archivo, el cual parece ser "nombreDelArchivo1.java". El modo de arreglarlo es que el archivo.java se llame igual a la clase. Sí la clase se llama Algo, el archivo debe llamarse Algo.java

Answer (score 0):

Comprrueba de que la clase se llame igual que el nombre del archivo y cuando la llames respeta tanto las mayusculas como las minusculas